# Any difference between "onClick" and get ref to add clickListener in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, frontend

Directly add a clickListener to component

```
<Grid onClick={this.state.event}/>
```

Set a ref then add clickListener

```
componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.grid).addEventListener('click', this.state.event);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.grid).removeEventListener('click', this.state.event);
}

<Grid fluid ref="grid"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check please React documentation

Refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Synthetic events: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

With refs you work with so-called uncontrolled components with browser-specific event data. You should be careful with refs, because you work with DOM element directly and it might lead to side effects in conjuction with React component's  lifecycle. Some examples to use refs might be handling focus, text selections, custom formatting and cursor positioning in form inputs, integration of non-React 3rd-party libraries etc. Usually libraries like [redux-form](https://redux-form.com) use refs heavily.

React's way with onClick (controlled components) provides cross-browser synthetic event data. React is smart enough and it uses only a single instance of event data to save memory. It is recommended to use controlled components to allow React fully control your components to avoid unintended behaviours, unless refs are explicitly needed.
If you develop some library to work with i.e. form elements, then using refs could be your convention.

Comment: If you're not going to explain it, this should probably be a comment.

Comment: No, this right here that I'm typing is a comment, that thing you posted is an answer, it should probably be a comment because these are just links, not an explanation

Answer (score 0):

String refs are deprecated in react 16.3 and refs are used mainly for the purpose of managing custom components and managing events like focus and selection. Use of refs is just an escape mechanism as it doesn't follow the conventional flow of parent-child hierarchy in react. Also, refs don't work for functional components, unless you are just accessing the Dom elements alone.

Read the don't overuse refs blog in react:
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Maintaining single source of Truth for child components:
https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html